# How can I pull out Todo items that are associated with a TodoList without using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Creating a todo app in which a TodoList has many Todos associated with it

e.g. "Shopping" TodoList has Todos like food, clothes etc.

I want to write code in a way so that when a user click on "Shopping" on the index page, a show page will render with all the Todos associated with it.

I think I need to write code within the getOneTodoList method but I`m not sure how I should structure it.

TodoListController.java

```
package com.teamlab.todolist.web;

import com.teamlab.todolist.domain.TodoList;
import com.teamlab.todolist.repository.TodoListRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/todoLists")
public class TodoListController {

    @Autowired
    TodoListRepository todoListRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllTodoLists(Model model) {
        List<TodoList> todoLists = todoListRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("todoLists", todoLists);
        return "todoLists/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public String getOneTodoList(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        TodoList todoList = todoListRepository.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("todoList", todoList);
        return "todoLists/show";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createTodoList(@ModelAttribute TodoList todoList) {
        todoListRepository.save(todoList);
        return "redirect:/todoLists";
    }

}
```

TodoList.java

```
package com.teamlab.todolist.domain;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class TodoList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String todoListName;

    public TodoList() {
    }

    public TodoList(String todoListName) {
        this.todoListName = todoListName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTodoListName() {
        return todoListName;
    }

    public void setTodoListName(String todoListName) {
        this.todoListName = todoListName;
    }
}
```

Todo.java

```
package com.teamlab.todolist.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String todoName;
    private LocalDate due_date;
    private Boolean completed;

    public Todo() {
    }

    public Todo(String todoName, LocalDate due_date, Boolean complete) {
        this.todoName = todoName;
        this.due_date = due_date;
        this.completed = complete;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTodoName() {
        return todoName;
    }

    public void setTodoName(String todoName) {
        this.todoName = todoName;
    }

    public LocalDate getDue_date() {
        return due_date;
    }

    public void setDue_date(LocalDate due_date) {
        this.due_date = due_date;
    }

    public Boolean getComplete() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setComplete(Boolean complete) {
        this.completed = complete;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. Pass "Shopping" id to your `getOneTodoList` method and it should fetch it's todo items and adde to model and pass to some jsp page to render it. As per code, you have done almost everything. What is the problem?

Comment: @gohil90 Im not sure how to use the id in the getOneTodoList method and find the todos that have the associations with the id. Don`t I have to do some comparisons or loops which I search through all the todos and see which todo has the matching id with the todolist?

Comment: That is the logic you have to think and write inside that method. Using that `id` to find appropriate Todos and show them. This could be from DB or from other repository based on your architechture.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a TodoList class containing objects of todo list representing each type of todos and their getters and setters. Like this.

```
class TodoList{
    Shopping shopping;
    Work work;
    //getters and setters
}
```

You can pass your id to the DAO layer and retrieve the TodoList associated with that user. Then call the getter method curresponding to that ID. Something like this. Here i assume you are using Hibernate.

```
@Repository
public class MapExample {
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public String todoListRepository(String id) {
    String query = "from TodoList WHERE username = :username";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(query).setString("username","admin");
    TodoList todoList = query.uniqueResult();
    if(id.equals("work")){
        model.addAttribute("todoList", todoList.getShopping())
    }
    if(id.equals("shopping")){
        model.addAttribute("todoList", todoList.getWork())
    }
    return "todoLists/show";
}
```

}